# PyTelegramBotApi. Изменение сообщений

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Нужно чтобы пользователь мог оставлять оценку на фото, при этом бот после оценки должен изменять фото на другое в том же сообщении. Бот один раз изменяет картинку, но затем выдаёт ошибку ссылаясь на попытку изменить идентичное прошлому сообщение.

TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400 Description: Bad Request: message is not modified: specified new message content and reply markup are exactly the same as a current content and reply markup of the message"

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def any_msg(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    callback_button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Одобряю", callback_data="poc")
    callback_button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Ме", callback_data="no_poc")
    keyboard.row(callback_button1, callback_button2)
    with open("test/bydlo.jpg", "rb") as image:
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, image, reply_markup=keyboard)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == "no_poc" or "poc":
            print("off")
            keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            callback_button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Класс", callback_data="anime")
            callback_button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Ме...", callback_data="non_anime")
            keyboard.row(callback_button1, callback_button2)
            with open("test/anime.jpg", "rb") as anime:
                bot.edit_message_media(media=types.InputMedia(type='photo', media=anime),chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, reply_markup=keyboard)

        elif call.data == "anime":
            keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            callback_button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Ме", callback_data="jeeraf")
            callback_button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Няяя", callback_data="very_anime")
            keyboard.row(callback_button2, callback_button1)
            with open("test/very_anime.jpg", "rb") as very_anime:
                bot.edit_message_media(media=types.InputMedia(type='photo', media=very_anime), chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка во втором callback обработчике, где вы проверяете call.data `if call.data == "no_poc" or "poc":`. Дело в том, что Python в данном случае всегда будет выдавать True, так как разбивает это выражение на `call.data == "no_poc"` и `"poc"`. Первое может быть и не всегда правда, зато второе всегда выдает True.

В этом случае я бы проверял это условие так:

```
if call.data in ["no_poc", "poc"]:
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. В очередной раз убеждаюсь, какой я ноль в Python.